# Tips to move existing angular + cordova to drupal gap?

Tags: javascript

I have created a mobile app using cordova and angular framework which is in production already. Now I am planning to switch to DrupalGap with my existing angular application.

I think support for angular in DrupalGap is only available in DrupalGap 2.x which is not useful for production use.

So to use DrupalGap 1.x in my existing app, do I have to remove the angular related code (like controllers,routes etc) and replace with DrupalGap menu and its callback?

Is there any other way to re-use the existing angular code in DrupalGap1.x?

Comment: Please remember polling for people's general experience with something doesn't suit Q+A, as it isn't a question with a definitive answer. Please ask more specific questions as they come up in your development. Many thanks

Comment: Hi Clive. okay. Thanks for pointing out that. I have edited my question now.